# Extract class labels along with cell values from HTML table

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm wondering if anyway can help extract these class labels, weights ('wl'), and cell values out of a table. I've provided a sample row below.

Sample rows are below.

```
<TABLE id='tbl5' class='display'>
<thead>
<TR><TH>Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>&nbsp;</TH><TH>Close</TH><TH>Tr&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>Mode&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>RevL (D)</TH><TH>MoM (D)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>Days&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>P/L %&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH><TH>Action&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</TH></TR>
</thead>

<tbody>
<TR><TD>Aaron's, Inc.</TD><TD>AAN</TD><TD>40.53</TD><TD class='c6' wl='44.92'>2</TD><TD class='c7' data-sort='3'></TD><TD>42.35</TD><TD class='c1' data-sort='-4.71'>-4.71 &#9650;</TD><TD od='6687' op='45.40'>17</TD><TD class='c10'>10.73%</TD><TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>Abiomed Inc.</TD><TD>ABMD</TD><TD>380.35</TD><TD class='c4' wl='242.10'>63</TD><TD class='c4' data-sort='1'></TD><TD>323.03</TD><TD class='c1' data-sort='10.00'>10.00 &#9650;</TD><TD od='6670' op='290.16'>28</TD><TD class='c10'>31.08%</TD><TD></TD></TR>
<TR><TD>American Campus Communities</TD><TD>ACC</TD><TD>38.18</TD><TD class='c7' wl='40.03'>39</TD><TD class='c6' data-sort='4'></TD><TD>39.52</TD><TD class='c2' data-sort='2.16'>2.16 &#9660;</TD><TD od='0' op='0.00'>0</TD><TD class='c13'>0.00%</TD><TD>Sell</TD></TR>
```

I'm trying to iterate over the tables, and the cells, but can't iterate over the cells it seems.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file.encode('utf-8'))

table = soup.find('table', id='tbl5')

rows = table.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')

for row in rows:
    cells = row.find_all("td")
    rn = cells[0].get_text()
    print(cells)
```

Traceback, list index out of range. Cells is None

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. What have you tried and what problems have you faced?

Comment: I'm able to iterate over the tables on the page, (theres 10), but I can't seem to iterate over the cels. When I do cells = row.find_all("td") I get None returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `td` directly, and be careful when getting `wl` attribute as not all `td`s have it:

```
 for td in soup.find_all('td'):
     wl = td.attrs.get('wl')  # not all td's have 'wl' attribute
     print(td.text, wl)

 #  Aaron's, Inc. None
 #  AAN None
 #  40.53 None
 #  2 44.92
 #   None
 #  42.35 None
 #  -4.71 ▲ None
 #  17 None
 #  10.73% None
 #   None
 #  Abiomed Inc. None
 #  ABMD None
 #  380.35 None
 #  63 242.10
 #   None
 #  323.03 None
 #  10.00 ▲ None
 #  28 None
 #  31.08% None
 #   None
 #  American Campus Communities None
 #  ACC None
 #  38.18 None
 #  39 40.03
 #   None
 #  39.52 None
 #  2.16 ▼ None
 #  0 None
 #  0.00% None
 #  Sell None
```